# What is the best way to cut path from NSString?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new in Cocoa. I have NSString . that looks like this

**Attribute: OtherAttributte: /users/user/etc...**

What is the best way to cut off and store separately that Path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rangeOfString and substringFromIndex.

```
NSString *path = @"Attribute: OtherAttributte: /users/user/etc";
NSRange x = [path rangeOfString:@"/"];
NSString *final = [path substringFromIndex:x.location];
```

This will work if your path starts with @"/".

Answer (score 2):

Use `rangeOfString:@"/"` to find the location of the first forward slash, and then `substringFromIndex:` to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

First approach:

```
NSString *path = @"tmp/scratch";
NSArray *pathComponents = [path pathComponents];
```

Second approach:

```
NSString *path = @" /users/user/etc";
NSArray *parts = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
```

Comment: I need to cut off all path from Attributes. I don't need to break down a path

Comment: Then why you don't ask exactly that?

Comment: What is the best way to cut off and store separately that Path? isn't it clear enough? Look at the question. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would use [componentsSeparatedByString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) which is a method of `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure whether you're asking how to get the path from the string of arguments, or how to get a part of the path, so I'll outline how I'd do both in separate steps below:

```
NSString *args = @"attribute1: attribute2: /users/user/etc";
NSString *path = [[args componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] last];
NSArray *pathComponents = [path pathComponents];
```

Obviously this relies on the path being the value of the final argument, but you could use a different means finding the path in the array produced from `args`.

Details of `NSString` methods can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), and `NSArray` methods [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

Comment: I need to get the path from arguments. Your first solution. It is nice. But what if folder name has @":" symbol in it, it won't work

Comment: @User1234 If you're paths will always be absolute, and you won't ever have any attributes that contain slashes you could get the substring by getting the `NSRange` from the first slash. Would this work for you?